# Speed up bash script that uses several find commands

Tags: linux, performance, git, bash, find

I have a bash script to add some files of a project to git and then synchronize that branch, as the amount of files has increased i have noticed the script has become much slower, so i want to figure out if I'm doing it the correct way.

This is the section of the script where the files are added:

```
echo "Adding files..."
find . -name '*.js' -exec git add {} \;
find . -name '*.html' -exec git add {} \;
find . -name '*.css' -exec git add {} \;
find . -name '*.py' -exec git add {} \;
find . -name '*.txt' -exec git add {} \;
find . -name '*.jpg' -exec git add {} \;
find . -name '*.sh' -exec git add {} \;

echo "Commit"
git commit -m "'$1'"
```

I'm not sure if making one single call to find would be faster than having all these separated commands, but I did it this way so it was simpler to remove some types of file or add new ones.

I would really appreciate any suggestion to make this more efficient, using the commands in a different way or using different commands is a completely acceptable answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find . \( -name '*.js'   -o \
          -name '*.html' -o \
          -name '*.css'  -o \
          -name '*.py'   -o \
          -name '*.txt'  -o \
          -name '*.jpg'  -o \
          -name '*.sh'   \) -exec git add {} +
```

This means you only scan the directory structure once, which is the primary way of speeding up 'multiple `find`s'; you replace 'multiple' with 'one'.  The `+` is a POSIX 2008 addition to `find` but makes it act more like `xargs` all on its own.  If it isn't available to you, consider using `-print` and `xargs` (or, if you're likely to have blanks in names and you have GNU `find` and `xargs`, then `-print0` and `xargs -0`, but if you have them, you (probably — but see comment) have the `+` notation too).

Comment: I tried this and figure out my version of bash does not support + in find so i used xargs -0 and its working fine now, thanks

Answer (score 6):

If git supports adding multiple files in one command, the simplest thing you can do is use the `+` suffix for `-exec`:

```
find . -name '*.js' -exec git add {} \+
```

This gathers a large number of files and passes them all to the command in one command line.

So what will be executed is:

```
git add a.js b.js c.js d.js
```

instead of

```
git add a.js
git add b.js
git add c.js
git add d.js
```

If you're processing hundreds or thousands of files, this will make a big difference in execution time.

To combine all the file patterns into a single `find` command, use find's "or" operator:

```
find . \( -name '*.js' -o   \
          -name '*.html' -o \
          -name '*.css' -o  \
          -name '*.py' -o   \
          -name '*.txt' -o  \
          -name '*.jpg' -o  \
          -name '*.sh' \) -exec git add {} +
```

The `\` before `(` and `)` is needed to protect them from their special shell meaning. You could equally use quotes instead: `'('`, `')'`.

`find` has some complicated options and one has to go to a bit of trouble to learn them and become familiar with them but I've saved myself a lot of effort over the years by being able to reel off a complicated `find` command rather than struggling with filtering file names through grep and awk and so forth.

One of my current favourite patterns for scanning through a maven/subversion java project while ignoring uninteresting files is:

```
find . \( \( \( -iname .svn -o -iname target -o -iname classes \) -type d -prune -false \) -o \( <your filter expression> \) \) -exec grep -li xxx {} +
```

Comment: Alternatively you can pipe the output through `xargs`, preferably by combining `find`'s switch `-print0` and `-0` for `xargs`, which makes them use null-terminated strings, so you won't have to take care about escaping spaces and similar stuff.

Comment: thank you very much for this detailed explanation i'm implementing it right now.

Comment: I implemented it using the code you show here but I get an error saying " find: missing arguments to '-exec' ", any idea of what am I missing?

Comment: @jeruki: On a reasonably modern linux? (less than 10 years old?) Maybe you need to escape the `+` symbol. It's hard to tell

Comment: the script is run from centos 6 and windows machines with cygwin, i guess the problem is the second one, but using xargs fixed it

Answer (score 2):

If you

- have Bash 4
- are searching by name only (not by other criteria)

you can use this too:

```
shopt -s globstar
git add **/*.{js,html,css,py,txt,jpg,sh}
```

---

Notes:

1. Brace expansion is executed before filename expansion, so this is equivalent to writing

   ```
   git add **/*.js **/*.html etc...
   ```
2. `globstar` enables recursive filename expansion via the keyword `**`.

Answer (score 2):

The `git add` command can do this without any other shell scripting.

```
git add -- '*.js' '*.html' '*.css' ...
```

Comment: this seems the most clear option, does this add subdirectories also?

Comment: ok I figured out the recursive part by trial/error, but then realized that when it does not find a single file with one of the extensions provided it fails with an error and aborts the operation, is there a way to tell it to continue even if a pattern is not matched?

Comment: It looks like `--ignore-errors` should do that for you, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: i tried that but it did not work, maybe ignore errors does not ignore all types of errors

Answer (score 1):

This may be faster:

```
F='\.js$|\.html$|\.css$|\.py$|\.txt$|\.jpg$|\.sh$'
find . | egrep $F | xargs git add
```

or some variation of it if you expect spaces or other special chars in filenames.

Comment: Just do not forget the trailing $ and leading \, if you use something like that. I made that mistake and lost the history of my Mercurial repository :(

Comment: If you spend a bit of effort up front to learn how to do this kind of filtering directly with `find` then you can use the -exec option to execute the command you need and the difficulty with "spaces or other special chars in filenames" goes away.